# When send advertising using Coded PHY in Ble5, How does controller know whether it should use s=2 or s=8?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

May i ask a question about coding scheme in Bluetooth lowenery 5 specification.

If a avertiser sends advertising with Coded PHY, how does the controller know whether it should use s=2 or s=8 ?

I can see there is a HCI command "LE Set Extended Advertising Parameters Command", which can set advertising using Coded PHY with "Primary_Advertising_PHY" parameter. But i did not get the command parameter to set the coded scheme s=2 or s=8.

So how does the controller know which coded scheme it should use?

Would anyone have any idea about this?
Thanks.